# MVC3 Binding to collection data model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, binding

My question isn't so much about displaying the data its about collecting changes to the data.

My specific scenario is the need to allow users to delete multiple items from a list.  I don't know if i'm even approaching this in a locgical way.

The List is a collection of Private Messages.  My view model has strings for To, From, Subject, and a bool for "Delete".

```
public class PrivateMessagesModel {

    public PrivateMessagesModel()
    {
        PrivateMessages = new List<PrivateMessageReceivedModel>();
    }

    public List<PrivateMessageReceivedModel> PrivateMessages;
}

public class PrivateMessageReceivedModel
{

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "From")]
    public string From { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Subject")]
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    public DateTime DateTimeSent { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Delete")]
    public bool Delete { get; set; }

}
```

The code to display looks like this.  And works ok.

@

```
model ScaleRailsOnline.Models.PrivateMessagesModel 
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Private Messages";
}
<div id="content">
    <div class="content">
        <h2>
            Private Messages</h2>
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        { <table>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.PrivateMessages.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.PrivateMessages[i].Delete)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.PrivateMessages[i].From)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
            </p>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is when I check a couple of the check boxes and hit the delete button, i get nothing back in the model.

Again, im sure i'm not approaching this in the right way.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In the @using (Html.BeginForm()) statement you have not specified any Controller and action methods where it will be posted.@using (Html.BeginForm("Index1", "Home",...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a controller associated to the Html.BeginForm where the form will be posted.
eg

```
 <div id="formid">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index1", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "formid",OnSuccess ="OnSuccess" }, new { id = "TheForm" }))
    {  
      @for (int i = 0; i < Model.PrivateMessages.Count; i++)
      {
          @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.PrivateMessages[i].Delete)
      }
      <input type="submit" name="name" value="Submit" />
    }
  </div>
```

On Controller

```
public ActionResult Index1(List<PrivateMessageReceivedModel> mod)
 {
   //Now in the mod you will get the value of the delete checkbox.
 }
```

Comment: I'm using the default form.  in the HTTPPost version of the index the other data on the form shows up, but not the collection of deletes. The collection shows 0 no matter how many items are checked.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a Controller class for your model. Then create method that return ActionResult type. and then create View of the newly created controller method.

Here is a sample code.

**Model Class**

```
namespace Mvc3Application1.Models
{
    public class PrivateMessage
    {
        public string From { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTimeSent { get; set; }
        public bool Delete { get; set; }
    }

    public class PrivateMessageRepository
    {
        public List<PrivateMessage> GetPrivateMessages()
        {
            List<PrivateMessage> myPrivateMessages=new List<PrivateMessage>();

            //add list of messages in the object myPrivateMessages
            myPrivateMessages.Add(new PrivateMessage { From = "abc@abc.com", Subject = "Subject 1", Message = "Message 1", DateTimeSent = DateTime.Now, Delete = false });
            myPrivateMessages.Add(new PrivateMessage { From = "abc1@abc.com", Subject = "Subject 2", Message = "Message 2", DateTimeSent = DateTime.Now, Delete = false });
            myPrivateMessages.Add(new PrivateMessage { From = "abc2@abc.com", Subject = "Subject 3", Message = "Message 3", DateTimeSent = DateTime.Now, Delete = false });
            myPrivateMessages.Add(new PrivateMessage { From = "abc3@abc.com", Subject = "Subject 4", Message = "Message 4", DateTimeSent = DateTime.Now, Delete = false });
            myPrivateMessages.Add(new PrivateMessage { From = "abc4@abc.com", Subject = "Subject 5", Message = "Message 5", DateTimeSent = DateTime.Now, Delete = false });

            return myPrivateMessages;
        }        
    }
}
```

**Controller class**

```
namespace Mvc3Application1.Controllers {
    public class PrivateMessageController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /PrivateMessage/

        // Show all the private messages       
        public ActionResult ListMessages()
        {
            return View(new Models.PrivateMessageRepository().GetPrivateMessages());
        }

        //delete the selected messages and return the collection
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ListMessages(FormCollection collection)
        {
            List<Models.PrivateMessage> messages = new Models.PrivateMessageRepository().GetPrivateMessages();//all messages
            List<Models.PrivateMessage> cloneMessages = new List<Models.PrivateMessage>();//messages left for deletion
            int noOfItems = 0;//no of items deleted
            int currentItem = 0;//current item in collection 'messages'

            string[] deletedItems = collection[0].Split(',');//return from HTML control collection

            for (int i = 0; i < deletedItems.Length; i++)
            {
                if (bool.Parse(deletedItems[i]) == false)//if checkbox is unchecked
                {
                    cloneMessages.Add(messages[currentItem]);//copy original message in cloneMessages collection
                }
                else //if checkbox is checked
                {
                    noOfItems++;                    
                    i++;
                }
                currentItem++;
            }
            ViewBag.Items = noOfItems + " message(s) deleted.";
            return View(cloneMessages);
        }

    } }
```

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<Mvc3Application1.Models.PrivateMessage>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Private Messages";
}

<h2>Private Messages</h2>
<div style="color:green;font-weight:bold;">@ViewBag.Items</div>
<br />
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>
                From
            </th>
            <th>
                Subject
            </th>
            <th>
                Message
            </th>
            <th>
                DateTimeSent
            </th>

        </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.Delete)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayTextFor(modelItem => item.From)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayTextFor(modelItem => item.Subject)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayTextFor(modelItem => item.Message)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayTextFor(modelItem => item.DateTimeSent)
            </td>

        </tr>
    }
    </table>

    <input type="submit"  value="Delete"/>
}
```

Comment: Im sorry, but your answer makes no sense.  I've shown the model and the code in the view that consumes the model and have indicated that all of that part works.  Thus indicating i have a controller.  Again my problem is the collection in the model is empty on a submittal.

Comment: In the controller class you have to create two Action methods, one for HttpGet and one for HttpPost actions. So when you press Submit button you have to call HttpPost action method (this method contains DB updation logic and returning of the result.)

Comment: I have added a sample code of your problem. Any question, please feel free to ask.

Comment: Thank you for the time to put the sample code there.  I will be out of town for a few days and will try this when I return.